# Visual Studio - Call stack does not trace back to user function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Ran into some access violation in visual studio 2010 and here's the callstack:
[image]

Most of the call stack are assembly code in the dll(almost illegible to  me). I want to trace back to the line in my code which caused the violation, but it seems there's no user function in the call stack.

How can I find the line in my function causing the violation ? Do I need to adjust some settings ?

Comment: Did you check other threads?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Check other threads ? How to check ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290866(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Thanks! I checked that and there's only main thread running.

Comment: Are you mixing Debug and Release in the same Qt based application? From your stack trace it does not look so though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting a reliable stack trace out of optimized C or C++ code is difficult.  The optimizer chooses speed over diagnosability.  The debugger needs PDB files for such code to know how to interpret the stack frames correctly and find the return address to the calling method.

Clearly you don't have these PDBs, you are getting the raw addresses from the operating system DLLs instead of their function names.  Getting those PDBs is pretty simple, Microsoft has a public server that does nothing but deliver those PDBs for any released version of Windows, including service packs and security updates.

Telling the debugger about that server is required, the feature is off by default.  It is particularly easy for VS2010, the server name is preprogrammed in the dialog, you only have to turn it on.  Tools + Options, Debugging, Symbols, tick the checkbox in front of "Microsoft Symbol Servers".  Set the cache directory, any writable directory will do.

Start debugging again, it will take a while at first to cache the PDBs.  When it is done, you'll see a greatly improved stack trace.  Accurate and with function names for the Windows DLLs.

Comment: Thanks ! I did get a improved call stack, which apparently gives function names than assembly offset. But when I double-clicked on a function name, an open file dialog popped up and ask me to find a .c file !  Em.... Do you see why am I missing these .c files ?

Comment: That will happen for parts of the windows api.

Comment: A bit of horse sense could help here.  Getting the source code for Windows requires finding a way to break into a vault in Redmond.  The usual advice applies if that's what you intend to do, don't do the crime if you can't do the time.  Since this is Qt, making it work on Linux is certainly an option.  It is however more productive to focus on the stack frames of *your* code.  If there's a bug somewhere then the 99.99% odds is that it is located in your code, not Windows nor Qt.

Comment: Hans: agreed, just tricky when there are no stack frames belonging to your code though - like in OP. I got the same issue, top of the call stack is VCRUNTIME140.dll, can't see anything higher. Can't see any other threads.